# Why don't newer versions of node remove __proto__ from request body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

When I send a  `PUT` request to my express server, `req.body` sometimes has a `__proto__` property, and other times not.

**Using node 0.10.26 and express 3.2.3**:

- When I put `{"a":"b", "__proto__": {}}`,
- Then `req.body` is `{"a":"b"}`

**Using node 4.1.0 and express 3.2.3**:

- When I put `{"a":"b", "__proto__": {}}`,
- Then `req.body` is `{"a":"b", "__proto__": {}}`

So newer versions of node do not strip the `__proto__` property. I actually liked this behaviour; now I have to write my own middleware which strips away the property. I think this has something to do with `bodyparser`. The weird thing is, though, that both tests have the same version of `express` (and hence the same version of `bodyparser`).

Can anyone give any motivation as to why this was changed? What is the recommended way of resolving this?

Comment: Use can use  body-parser as a separate module. https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#expressconnect-top-level-generie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither **express** nor **node** are responsible for this behavior. This has actually been changed a long time ago in **V8**, for compatibility and spec conformance.

- Old behavior (`__proto__` is stripped):

  ```
  > var x = JSON.parse('{"__proto__":[]}');
  > x.hasOwnProperty('__proto__');
  false
  ```
- New behavior (`__proto__` is not stripped):

  ```
  > var x = JSON.parse('{"__proto__":[]}');
  > x.hasOwnProperty('__proto__');
  true
  ```

Sources :

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115055
- https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1310

### Solution:

Like you said, you can write a simple middleware to strip the property yourself:

```
function stripProto(req, res, next) {
  delete req.body.__proto__;
  next();
}
// ...
app.use(stripProto);
```

Comment: Oh, that was why my google searches didn't find anything. Thanks for the clarification!